# Routes/serve file (laravel/node js) vs simple html 'a href' in order to navigate from page to page

Tags: php, html, node.js, laravel

It may be dumb, I am begginer in server side and I don't truly understand some things. I ve watched some tutorials both of node js and laravel (laravel just for curiosity and research). It rised me a big perplexity. 
Background(an example from my last read):

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return 'Hello World';
});

Route::post('foo/bar', function () {
   return 'Hello World';
});

Route::put('foo/bar', function () {
   //
});

Route::delete('foo/bar', function () {
   //
});
```

I know laravel is a framework and first to learn pure php, but I've saw same thing in pure php and in node js (serving files) and my question is not about this.
I tagged all 3 because my question is one:
Why they use server side in order to navigate from page to page instead of just using html a href? I mean, what are the benefits? Hope it makes sense for you what I've asked

Comment: To ensure you visit only the pages allowed, and with the correct format. And to ensure next programmer to look at your code knows (or yourself after two months) doesn't go crazy to understand the structure of the site. Just needs to read the routes file.

Comment: That is a good reason of security.

Comment: But... after that, I won't be able to use stuffs like mywebcron...right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefits are you can dynamically create the html page (in this case) instead of just sending a static html page.

This means you can read some data from the database into a **model** and then update the **view** accordingly.

A simple use case:

- */user/mitchy* would show a page that says "Welcome Mitchy"
- */user/someoneelse* would show a page that says "Welcome Someone Else"

if you went to /user.html it would only be able to send the html "Welcome User"

I'd suggest reading the Laravel getting started tutorial for more info

Comment: True. but it was using a simple use case addressing the question "Why they use server side in order to navigate from page to page instead of just using html a href?" ... if you just wanted static content, then theres no need to route, just put html in the public folder and link to that. It will be (marginally) better performance anyway

Comment: I would argue that defeats the point of using Laravel's sugar, MVC modularisation and standardisation... but thats just my opinion. Feel free to answer the question directly... my point is this: why route? its a gateway drug to laravel's power

Comment: I'm not talking about Laravel in particular or PHP in particular. I'm talking about the old way of doing things when you throw `.php` or `.aspx` or whatever tech you use into a public directory and basically your file system layout becomes your routing vs. newer MVC/MVVM frameworks where you have a singe point of entry where the routing happen. You could do DB access and contend generation in the old way too.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer:

Modern web libraries/frameworks work this way (1) to enable the usage of shorter, more human readable URIs (routes), (2) to decouple the directory structure of the server from the URIs.

## Long answer:

First of all `<a href>` is not the only way to navigate websites. `<a>` can only use the `GET` method to navigate to a resource. If you need to send other types of requests you use `<form method="">` (let's leave AJAX and all the JavaScript aside).
Now for example you have a blog website. If you build it in old style routing you have routes tied to the file locations in the files system. So in the directory which is defined as website's root the you have `/posts.php` page which allows you to see blog posts (`GET` method), add (`POST` method), delete (`DELETE`) and edit (`PUT` or `PATCH`). Also you allow not only to see a specific post but also to view post by year, month and date.
So you have something like this somewhere on your site:

```html
    <!-- Go to the posts page which shows the list of all posts -->
    <a href="/posts.php">All posts</a>
    <hr>

    <!-- Show posts by year / month / date -->
    <form method="GET" action="/posts.php">
        <select name="year">
            <option>
            <option>2017
            <option>2016
        </select>
        <select name="month">
            <option>
            <option value="1">Jan
            <option value="2">Feb
            <option value="3">Mar
        </select>
        <select name="date">
            <option>
            <option>1
            <option>2
            <option>3
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Show</button>
    </form>
    <hr>

    <!-- Add a post -->
    <form method="POST" action="/posts.php">
        <textarea>
        </textarea>
        <button type="submit">Add post</button>
    </form>
    <hr>

    <!-- Edit a post -->
    <form method="PATCH" action="/posts.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="2"/>
        <textarea>
        </textarea>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
    <hr>

    <!-- Delete a post -->
    <form method="DELETE" action="/posts.php">
        <select name="post_id">
            <option>
            <option value="1">Post title 1
            <option value="2">Post title 2
            <option value="3">Post title 3
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Delete post</button>
    </form>
```

All this forms and the link are pointing to the `/posts.php` page. Which means that the `posts.php` will most likely have all the logic to handle all these cases. It will be one spaghetto piece of code which checks what method was used and acts accordingly. Of cause you can separate the code into different files. Let's say you make a `delete_post.php` file and put deletion logic there and then you `require` the `delete_post.php` inside the `posts.php`. Now you need to configure your web server to disallow users to execute `delete_post.php` directly. Or you can move all deletion logic to `delete_post.php` and allow to execute it directly. But now your website sends `DELETE` request to `/delete_post.php` instead of `/posts.php` which does not make too much sense. That's the problem (2) of having URIs coupled with files on the file system.
Now let's concentrate on the `form` which shows posts by year / month / date. When you press the *Show* button it will go to `/posts.php?year=2016&month=1&date=1`. Which is a long and ugly URI. Now, there are URI styling recommendations like this one: https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI (I saw other similar recommendations from W3C or WHATWG few years ago but I can't find them now). Main points of these recommendations are:

- Make URIs easily readable and editable
- Make URIs more semantic
- Don't use technology specific extensions inside URIs (like `.php`, `.aspx`, `.jsf` etc.)
- Avoid using query strings (the part after `?`)

**The solution:**

The solution is to use a single point of entry and then route from there. Let's take Laravel for example. In the default configuration Laravel serves all the static content like images, CSS and JS from the file system. All the rest of the requests go to the `/index.php`. `/index.php` does some preliminary work and then sends the request to the router. In Laravel routes are defined in the `routes/web.php` file (there is also and `routes/api.php` file, but it's not important now). Now Laravel is an MVC framework so the routes usually don't look like this:

```
Route::post('foo/bar', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

They usually look like this:

```
Route::post('foo/bar', 'ControllerName@ActionName');
```

So for the get posts by year / month /date the route would look something like this:

```
Route::get('posts/{year?}/{month?}/{date?}', 'PostsController@show');
```

This route would instruct Laravel to search for `PostsController` class, call its `show` method and pass the `year`, `month` and `date` arguments to that method. '?' at the end of the argument means it is optional, Laravel will match this route even if there is no year, month and date.
The show method would look something like this:

```
public function show($year = null, $month = null, $date = null) {
    //if there are no arguments then show all posts
    //if there is only the year then show post from that year
    //if there is year and month then show post from that year and month
    //etc.
}
```

Now the URI looks like this `/posts/2017/1/1`. The user can easily delete the date and get posts for the year + month and so on. All modern web libraries / frameworks work pretty much the same in regards to routing.